# Where should we return a rental car in London?

Tags: car-rentals

We will be returning a rental car to London on a Monday afternoon in September. Is it best to return it at LHR, or drive into the city somewhere? we will be checking into a hotel in Bloomsbury.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE. Usually when you rent a car, there is a return agency indicated on your contract (often the same as the one you picked up the car). If you do not return it to this agency, you will likely pay extra fees. So you should read your booking receipt/contract and you will find where it is the cheapest to return it.

Comment: I'm guessing they have an itinerary planned but haven't booked the car yet.

Comment: As a general rule, unless you're a confident driver + good navigator + understand about things like congestion charging + bus lane fines + parking rules, as a tourist you don't want to drive in London if you don't have to!

Comment: @dlanod so they already know they will drive back on a monday in september (in 6 months) but cannot decide where to stop. I find that funny

Comment: @Vince I'm in exactly the same scenario (see my last two questions about rental locations), but in June-July. :)  People plan holidays in different ways.

Comment: @dlanod I am not surprised about people planning their holidays in advance, I am surprised by the precision of some information (they will arrive on a monday and booked a hotel), but not saying where they picked up the car. And I am in no way judgemental, I am just trying to understand the question.

Comment: It depends mostly on where you picked it up and from which company. If you are flexible in this respect, you need to tell us a little more about your plans (where/when are you arriving, where do you want to go) to get comprehensive answers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you're travelling back from and where you picked up the car.

If you've been located in London with the rental car, I would just return it in London.

If you've been travelling outside of London, I'd investigate dropping off somewhere on your way back to London that has a direct train service to London, either Heathrow or other locations along the way.  Other locations will probably be even less busy than Heathrow, so may be preferable.

It's worth noting that dropping off or picking up at airports often have surcharges attached, so I would check that as well before settling on Heathrow.  In addition, picking up and dropping off at separate locations can attract a surcharge so that would also be worth checking.

Comment: The best drop-off location may be a non-airport location on the route you are taking into London.